# Defining point from other points [tikz]

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can someone epxlain me tf is going here ?
Why are red and blue not at the same position ?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) arc (260:280:20);
\draw (6.946,0) coordinate (A1);
\draw (6.946,-2) coordinate (B1);
\draw[rotate around={10:(A1)}, red] (A1) -- (6.946,-2) coordinate (B2);
\draw[red] (B2) node {$\bullet$};
\draw[rotate around={10:(A1)}, blue] (A1) -- (B1) coordinate (B2);
\draw[blue] (B2) node {$\bullet$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

what the tikz picture look like
[image: render]

i'm so confused

Comment: `(B1)` is a fixed point in your diagram. It won't get transformed by transformations on the path. You need to do `([rotate around=10:(A1)]B1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer